# Atomically get Multiset entry in ConcurrentHashMultiset (guava)

Tags: java, guava

I have a `ConcurrentHashMultiset` and I'd like to atomically retrieve the count of an element and the total size of the multiset.  Something like

```
final double count = set.count(element);
final double size = set.size();
```

but as an atomic operation. Is there any way to do that without using read/write mutexes for all usages of the set or creating an immutable copy of the set?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ConcurrentHashMultiset.html#size%28%29) it seems that size() returns an element with no guarantees.

Comment: Could you describe the use case, please? I'm curious of how this could be theoretically applied? :-)

Comment: Roughly, I need to get a valid probability of an item being in the set. This involves computing count/size (for a naive maximum likelihood estimation). In order to speed up I need to parallelize the sampler (the think that acquires the probability) and the threads that alter the multiset...

Comment: Huh, I see - a nice example. It's interesting if there is other than a `synchronizedMap` solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into an implementation of `ConcurrentHashMultiset`:

```
 private final transient ConcurrentMap<E, AtomicInteger> countMap;
```

There is no non-blocking way to get atomically two values out of this. These are two separate operations.

`toArray()` is non-atomic for this operation as it non-blockingly relies on iterating over a list of `AtomicInteger`s which may change in time.

Answer (score 3):

Use `toArray` to get a copy of it! Everything else makes no sense. Even if were possible to get the size and the count atomically, you could never be sure that the set isn't modified by another thread right after that.

Apart from that: Size isn't guaranteed to return an exact value! If another threads modify the set while `size` is called, it is undefined weather or not these modifications affects the size calculation.